# Fetching specific data from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table that looks like this: (exported from PHPMyAdmin)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
 `parent` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `message` longtext NOT NULL,
 `authorid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp2` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Basically, this is the table that holds the topics for my forum system.

- parent indicates the category it's in
- id indicates the topic id
- id2 indicates the order of replies (1 = original post, 2 = first reply, etc.)
- title indicates the topic title
- message indicates the text
- authorid indicates the author of the message (stored in a different database)
- timestamp indicates post time
- timestamp2 indicates edited time

So I'm having trouble creating a most recent post page, that I can include on other pages. What I want to fetch, is the original, most recent topic posted.

Easier said:

- Highest id there is
- Lowest id2 (AKA id2 must be equal to 1, since that is the first post)
- Fetch all info from that row in the table

Please note: the id's are NOT auto increment, since I manually set it to the upcoming number using PHP when a topic is posted. AKA I do not think LAST_INSERT_ID() will work.

The code I have so far for doing this is posted on Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/cyARYeT1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understood well, your requirement :P

But, however what can i understand is, that you want topic display the most recent topic posted or modified.

> SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id timestamp2 DESC.

This query will work, if you are filling, timestamp 2 even when the topic is created.

**Second solution**

```
> SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id timestamp DESC. in array t1
 SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id timestamp2 DESC. in array t2

Then merge t1 and t2 in descending order by comparing timestamp field of t1 and timestamp2 field of t2.
```

> Then loop on third array in descending order...

Hope this works .

Comment: The first method is the easiest and it works like a charm after several tests, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    topics
WHERE
    id IN ((SELECT id from topics order by id desc limit 1)) /* set a higher limit if you want to pull more recent posts */
ORDER BY
    id desc,
    id2 asc
```

In English the SQL translates to:

> Get everything from the topics table
>
> Where ID is the highest available at the time of this query
>
> Order by ID ascending first and then ID2 in descending order

Comment: Not sure if you saw the original post but I've updated the SQL now

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this:

```
SELECT * FROM topics
ORDER BY id DESC, id2 ASC
LIMIT 1
```

On a sidenote, I think you would be a lot happier if your fields for post time and edited time where named `post_time` and `edited_time`, respectively, instead of `timestamp` and `timestamp2`. Same goes for `id` and `id2`

Comment: That bit of SQL indeed worked, thanks! I do understand that yes, I can change it of course but as long as I, myself understand it, it's fine :P I'll still change it anyways incase I have other questions.